# iOS Simulator issue not showing list from index 0, when display array in a table view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, xcode6.3

I am using `xcode6.3`

I created a array in the `SimpleViewTable.m` file

```
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
```

When i run the program.

In the simulator screen i got result but it start from the `@"Vegetable Curry"`.

It is not showing result from index 0.

When i click on the table item and drag down, then i see previous items.
and it again moves up.

Please give me a suggestion so that i can resolve this issue.

Comment: can u perform this action of initializing the array and throw again the feedback what happened? tableData=  [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B", nil]

Comment: Do you use a UIViewController containing a UITableView or did you use a complete UITableViewController? Also, do you use some HeaderViews for the Table?

Comment: @Rajan, i tried with [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects.... but i am getting same issue.

Comment: @itinance, i used UITableView to display a products list, present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that when you drag down the table view, you are able to see the index 0 record and then it again goes in hiding state; indicates that there is something wrong with either `contentOffset` or `contentInset` of table view. 
Keep a break point in `viewDidAppear:` and check if `contentOffset` is set to a non-zero value. Reset it to zero if as given below. Same goes for `contentInset` property

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);// If class is child of UITableViewController
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

OR

```
objTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);// If you are using a UITableView object explicitly
[objTableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Hi Gandalf, thanks for your response.. could you please guide me how can i set contentInset and contentOffset to 0

Comment: Check the edited answer, but first ensure that your `contentOffset` indeed is coming as non-zero. This is the pretty obvious cause but there can be something else wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, we have got the same issue and found solution on it. You need to
  reload your tableview twice:-

  See below code for example:-

  [tableview reloadData];

  [self performSelector:@selector(refreshData) withObject:nil
  afterDelay:0.0];

  -(void)refreshData {   [tableview reloadData]; }